# « Qu'est-ce qui fait quelque chose » et « C'est quoi, qui fait quelque chose »

Tags: grammaire, questions

Un chapitre de la troisième édition de *Controverses* traite des différentes façons de poser les questions. Il indique qu'il y a des formes courtes et longues, ce que je savais déjà. Le texte affirme aussi qu'on ne peut pas raccourcir une question comme :

> « Qu'est-ce qui fait ce bruit ? »

J'ai pensé à :

> « C'est quoi, qui fait ce bruit ? »

Je crois que cette question est moins formelle que l'autre mais reste quand même acceptable.

Ai-je raison ? Si oui, puis-je utiliser cette forme pour d'autres questions comme « Qu'est-ce qui fait quelque chose » ?

Si j'ai fait des fautes, n'hésitez pas à les corriger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vous pouvez utiliser les deux - mais la forme (avec ou sans la virgule):

> "C'est quoi, qui fait ce bruit?"

est très familière, voire presque "vulgaire". De plus, l'effet sonore est moins heureux que:

> Qu'est-ce qui fait ce bruit?"

Il se peut qu'une forme:

> Que fait ce bruit?

au sens de `quelle est la source de ce bruit` ait existé dans le passé, mais si c'est cas, plus personne ne l'utilise de nos jours.  Aussi, de nos jours, cette tournure serait comprise comme: `quelle est la conséquence de ce bruit` - donc attention au glissement de sens. On peut rencontrer, rarement:

> Quoi donc me retient auprès d'elle?

Mais cette tournure est en passe de devenir complètement périmée, à mon avis: si on demande à un Français aujourd’hui si c’est correct, la réponse est plus souvent “non” ou "je ne sais pas" que “oui". Curieusement, cette tournure peut sonner précieuse (“Quoi donc me retient auprès d'elle?” ou peut-être “vulgaire” (“Quoi donc que tu verrais en plus?”), ceci étant un jugement de style qui n’engage que moi (ces empilements de sons "qu" sont maladroits).

Notons aussi que la virgule dans `"C'est quoi, qui fait ce bruit?"` n'est pas très heureuse. En effet, on pourrait comprendre:

> C'est quoi? Qui fait ce bruit?

ou bien:

> C'est quoi qui fait ce bruit?

La deuxième forme étant dans un registre de language moins soutenu que la première (et les sens sont aussi différents, bien entendu).

On peut effectivement utiliser `Qu'est-ce qui <fait quelque chose>` dans d'autres situations, par exemple:

> Qu'est-ce qui fait voler les avions?
>
> Qu'est-ce que mangent les écureuils? (mieux: Que mangent les écureuils?)
>
> Qui est-ce qui a gagné les élections? (mieux: Qui a gagné les élections?)
>
> Qu'est-ce qui se passe là-bas?
>
> Qu'est-ce qu'il a dit à la réunion? (mieux: Qu'a-t'il dit à la réunion?)

Mais utiliser une formule "courte" comme:

> C'est quoi qui fait voler les avions?

ne serait pas acceptable à l'écrit, serait pour le moins maladroit, et serait à mon avis corrigé à l'école primaire, en principe (modulo le fait que la langue se dégrade/change tous les jours)

Comment: Vulgaire, c'est un peu trop. La grammaire du français parlé et ses formes ne sont pas celles du français écrit. On entend couramment et partout des formes comme: C'est quoi, qui fait ce bruit?". Il faut faire la distinction sinon les gens arrivent dans un pays francophone et pigent rien. "Il veut quoi, ce type là?". Il m'a fallu des années pour bien saisir cette distinction. Au moins cinq ans en France avant de pouvoir parler comme les gens  parlent vraiment et non pas comme dans les grammaires. Cela ne veut pas dire  parler comme un ignard. Sufft de voir des filmes en français.

Comment: T'as raison mon pote. I'se prend pour qui cuila d'abord? Y'a que les nases qui parle comme la gramaire.

Comment: Soyons honnêtes. Là vous dépassez un peu mon intention. Il y a quand même une différence. Je suppose que vous n'assistez pas aux filmes en français. Je suis une femme, alors difficilement ton pôte. Même les profs seraient d'accord avec mon opinion à ce sujet. Et puis, qui a parlé de faire des fautes d'orthographe? Pas moi.

Comment: http://www.lpl-aix.fr/~fulltext/4849.pdf Un peu de lecture s'avère nécessaire pour les récalcitrants. :)

Comment: Vos échanges m'ont un peu surpris ; personne n'a parlé de l'adverbe interrogatif dans une phrase comme _d'où vient ce bruit ?_ Ensuite, _qu'est-ce qui fait ce bruit_, c'est que et non qui (est-ce...). Je ne comprends pas qu'on accepte sans broncher la virgule (superflue) entre _c'est quoi_ et _qui fait ce bruit_, et pour moi ça se dit d'un trait comme la phrase avec _qu'est-ce que_ : _c'est quoi qui fait ce bruit(-là)_. Autrement je (Qc.) reconnais _c'est quoi ça ?_ (littéralement, ou la surprise) et _qui fait ce bruit ?_ pour savoir quelle personne fait un bruit. Merci. cc @Lambie

Comment: La virgule n'est pas, a mon avis, un gros problème. Contrairement a l'anglais, nous utilisons peut-être plus de virgules, en particulier entres propositions, et "qui fait ce bruit" est une subordonnée relative. Avec ou sans, ca me semble bon.

Comment: @Tu ne ...: "Ensuite, qu'est-ce qui fait ce bruit, c'est que et non qui (est-ce...)." - que voulez-vous demander ici, je ne comprends pas bien?

Comment: Oui, "qui est-ce qui fait ce bruit?" se rapporte a une personne, mais "qu'est-ce qui fait ce bruit", pas nécessairement. Pour l'histoire de la virgule, je pense surtout qu'elle introduit une nuance d'insistance ou d'irritation. Mais le "qui" qui suit ne se rapporte pas forcément a une personne... Ah je vois maintenant - vous comprenez "C'est quoi! Qui fait ce bruit?", mais je pensais a "C'est quoi qui fait ce bruit". On peut comprends les deux. Le "!" serait plus clair pour le sens que vous voulez.

Comment: « Que fait ce bruit ? » est du français moderne et correct. Sa signification est cependant tout autre: « Quelle est la conséquence de ce bruit » au lieu de l'origine avec « qu'est-ce qui fait ce bruit ? ».

Comment: @jiliagre - oui - et comme le sens est si différent, je ne voulais pas le mentionner dans cette réponse.

Comment: Il n'est pas trop tard pour le faire. Écrire qu'une forme a peut-être existé mais n'est plus utilisée alors qu'il s'agit en fait d'une phrase de français courant mérite d'être expliqué à quelqu'un qui apprend le français et pour qui les sens différents n'ont rien d'implicite.

Comment: OK, je vais l'ajouter. Etes-vous un "native speaker" en francais, ou pas - juste pour svoir.

Comment: @jiliagre - aussi "que fait ce bruit?" ne fais pas beaucoup de sens, car un bruit ne "fait" rien. La tournure est grammaticale, mais n'a pas de sens dans ce cas precis.

Comment: @Frank, oui, je suis un *native speaker* tout ce qu'il y a de plus français. C'est une bonne question car beaucoup de réponses, ces derniers temps, proviennent de personnes pour qui ce n'est manifestement pas le cas. Attention « Faire du sens » est un [anglicisme](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3499). La question n'est pas courante mais il est relativement facile de trouver des contextes où elle est à peu près plausible : « Que fait ce bruit ? – Il prévient que le frigo n'est pas bien fermé; – Il fait fuir les oiseaux de la piste de décollage; – Il énerve ma femme », etc.

Comment: @jiliagre - oui, il faudrait qu'on s'identifie mieux. Même parmi les francophones, il pourrait y avoir des tournures Suisses, ou Belges, ou Québecoises, ou comme moi, des anglicismes auxquels je dois faire attention :-) (je suis _native_ aussi, mais je vis depuis très longtemps aux US).

Comment: Un autre anglicisme, les adjectifs issus de nom propres ne prennent pas de majuscule en **f**rançais. PS: Pour que je sois correctement informé des commentaires qui me sont adressés, il vaut mieux utiliser la *completion* de l'interface qui évite les erreurs. Mon pseudo commence par J L L, pas par J I L.

Comment: Merci! :-) Je finirais par y arriver.

Answer (score 2):

> Ai-je raison ?

Techniquement non, car la phrase envisagée est plus longue que la phrase originale: deux caractères et une syllabe en plus.

En supprimant la virgule qui n'a guère de justification, on trouve une forme de question très couramment utilisée en français parlé (registre populaire).

> « C'est quoi qui fait ce bruit ? »

Il existe aussi une forme très rare et plus concise. Elle consiste simplement à utiliser « **quoi** » comme sujet :

> « Quoi donc fait ce bruit ? »

« Quoi » doit être suivi d'un mot ou d'une proposition en incise pour que la forme soit correcte. « *Quoi fait ce bruit ? » est donc inacceptable mais « Quoi, dit-il, fait ce bruit ? » est grammatical.

On rencontre cette tournure chez Flaubert:

> « [Quoi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quoi) donc t'étonne ? » (Mme Bovary, t. 2, 1857, p. 228)

---

> Si oui, puis-je utiliser cette forme pour d'autres questions comme « Qu'est-ce qui fait quelque chose » ?

Bien sûr, « **[c'est quoi qui](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/c%E2%80%99est_quoi_qui)…** » peut remplacer « **qu'est-ce qui…** » dans la plupart de cas, mais reste d'un registre populaire incompatible avec un français soutenu ou écrit. Son utilisation semble en croissance soutenue, probablement car la forme est plus simple que « qu'est-ce qui » et son registre deviendra sans doute rapidement plus proche de familier que de populaire.

Voici quelques exemples couramment employés en français parlé :

> « C'est quoi qui pue ? »
>
> « C'est quoi qui va se passer ? »
>
> « C'est quoi qui est lourd comme ça dans ta valise ? »
>
> « C'est quoi qui t'empêche d'y aller ? »
>
> « C'est quoi qui me gratte dans le dos ? »
>
> « C'est quoi qui l'a énervé ? »
>
> « C'est quoi qui cloche ? »
>
> etc.

Comment: Merci--je ne pense pas à comparer la quantité des caractères, mais simplement au remplacement de la question. Quand même, votre réponse m'aide beaucoup.

Comment: Je comprend, mais la question originale contenait: «  Mais il dit aussi qu'on ne peut pas faire courte une question comme » puis « moi je me suis pensé à » qui semblait bien indiquer que la phrase ne pouvait pas être réduite. Afin d'éviter les erreurs d'interprétation, il est tout à fait possible de poser sur le site French.stackexchange des questions à la fois en anglais et en français.

Comment: Im gonna do this in english precisely to avoid errors--i originally was looking at making the question shorter. I didnt realize the second version was actually longer, but i wasnt interested in letter counts. I apologize if there was any confusion.

Comment: Le "quoi dont fait ce bruit" n'est plus utilisé du tout. Je ne l'ai jamais entendu.

Comment: @Frank, j'ai indiqué que cette tournure était très rare. Elle est d'un niveau de langage élevé. Colette: « Quoi donc me retient auprès d'elle ? », mais pas que: https://twitter.com/blogromainparis/status/597442417646817281

Comment: @Frank Une autre utilisation récente : [Quoi donc que tu verrais en plus?](http://warlherm.free.fr/index.php?topic=260.15)

Comment: OK - je vais l'ajouter a ma reponse - mais cette forme est suffisamment rare pour que beaucoup de francais ne la trouvent deja plus "correcte". J'ai demande autour de moi, et la premiere reaction, c'etait de dire "hein? non, on ne dit pas ca".